# How do I rearrange a Dataframe structure in python

Tags: python, dataframe

Hi I have an extract from excel file which which is converted into a dataframe. The first column has dates followed by entries/statements for those dates and the second column has values (as shown below)

```
Entries.             Value
01/03/2020           
Entry statement abc    12
Entry statement xyz     3
Entry statement ttt    34
Entry statement ffg     5
Entry statement erer   45
02/03/2020  
Entry statement frf    23
Entry statement fgf    34
Entry statement afgh    4
Entry statement abcf   34
03/03/2020  
Entry statement abcr   34
Entry statement tfgg   45
Entry statement abc    45
```

how do I rearrange the dataframe so that it looks more like how its shown below

```
Date        Entry                 Value
01/03/2020  Entry statement abc     12
01/03/2020  Entry statement xyz      3
01/03/2020  Entry statement ttt     34
01/03/2020  Entry statement ffg      5
01/03/2020  Entry statement erer    45
02/03/2020  Entry statement frf     23
02/03/2020  Entry statement fgf     34
02/03/2020  Entry statement afgh     4
02/03/2020  Entry statement abcf    34  
03/03/2020  Entry statement abcr    34  
03/03/2020  Entry statement tfgg    45  
03/03/2020  Entry statement abc     45
```

Comment: please show some code

Comment: The answer to “is it possible” is almost always “Yes” – you’re using a general-purpose language on a computer that is all but a Turing machine.  The question you may intend to ask, “how do I do it”, is too unfocused for Stack Overflow.  Repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have pandas dataframe `df`.

Step 1: Create a column with the date:

```
df['Date'] = np.nan
date = None
for i, row in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    potential_date = row['Entries.']
    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(potential_date, %x)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    df.loc[i, 'Date'] = date
```

Step 2. Delete extra rows

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0) # you may need to specify the subset
```

Comment: thanks a lot Kate, I get the logic! However, for some reason  'potential_date = row['Entries.'] isn't working. "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str". you know what's happening there?

Comment: Perhaps,  you need to use `row[0]` instead of the name of the column.

Comment: perfect! that worked. thanks again